# Desearalising list in JSON response

Tags: c#, json, list

I am using the C# `JavaScriptSerializer` object to successfully deserialize JSON responses made up of classes or arrays of classes.

What kind or class or variable do I desearalise a list response like this into?

```
{
   "symbols": {
       "AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham",
       "AFN":"Afghan Afghani",
       "ALL":"Albanian Lek",
       "AMD":"Armenian Dram"
   }
}
```

Comment: Try your friend [Online Json to Class Converter](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: You can create two class and then deserialize this.

Comment: @Gary K , don't forget to mark answers that helped you as correct, thank you

Comment: Me being stupid but I can't see a way to do that

Answer (score 1):

A simple `Dictionary<string, string>` would do great, but if you want it to be a class, you will need one more level of nesting:

Json

```
"rapidSymbols":{
   "symbols":{
     "AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham",
     "AFN":"Afghan Afghani",
     "ALL":"Albanian Lek",
     "AMD":"Armenian Dram",
     ...
     }
}
```

Code

```
class RapidSymbols
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Symbols {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But needed this class class RapidSymbols{
        public IDictionary<string, string> Symbols { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Your current JSON is just a class nested in another property. If you change your JSON to the below then you can use a Dictionary instead and it will be dynamic.

```
{
   "symbols":[
      {
         "AED":"United Arab Emirates Dirham"
      },
      {
         "AFN":"Afghan Afghani"
      },
      {
         "ALL":"Albanian Lek"
      },
      {
         "AMD":"Armenian Dram"
      }
   ]
}

class RapidSymbols
{
    public IDictionary<string, string> Symbols {get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But I dont know how many 'symbols' I am going to get back so it needs to be dynamic.Sorry I should have made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize to this classes

```
public class Symbols
{
    public string AED { get; set; }
    public string AFN { get; set; }
    public string ALL { get; set; }
    public string AMD { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Symbols symbols { get; set; }
}
```